# Moving files with if statements in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to do the following (I've written in what I've been able to work out (line 3 and 4), and then described what I'd like to do on other lines in caps, with additional comments in the hashtags)
First time using Powershell today so forgive me!
I'm guessing the IF part will need to all be on one line?
Each line runs independently... correct? Or not if it's all in one script?

```
CHECK FOR .TXT FILES IN DIRECTORY IF MULTIPLE, OPEN EXPLORER WINDOW TO FOLDER (If count of *.txt in folder is > 1, open directory...?)
IF ONLY ONE .TXT EXISTS (If count of *.txt in folder is = 1)
Move-Item <dir1*.txt> <dir2> #Move item from directory to new directory
<dir> #Execute program, does this need 'execute' or some parameter?
ELSE END #don't attempt to run the program if nothing has been moved
```

Comment: Hey buddy.  Step 1 here is to learn the commands for what you're trying to do.  Go to your favorite search engine and look up some PowerShell commands.  I'd look up examples of Get-ChildItem and Invoke-Item to see if those can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First day learning a language is both very confusing, and very, very confusing.

I'm throwing you a bone here.  :D

Step 1:  You need to figure out how to find all the text files in your folder.  You probably know how to do this in CMD, right?  The command "dir" will list all the junk in your directory, right?  Guess what? Most of the command-line cmdlets work in PowerShell too.  They're called aliases.

The native command to get the contents of a directory is `Get-ChildItem` but it has a few aliases, one of which is `dir`.  If you type `Get-ChildItem` or `dir` you'll get the same results.

So let's say you want to get all the text files in "MyDirectory" only.  Use a wildcard "*" followed by ".txt" like so:

```
Get-ChildItem "MyDirectory\*.txt"
```

That will give you a list of all your .txt files in that directory.  But you also have an if statement you want to use right?  And it's based on the number of .txt files in that directory?  Let's meet variables.

Declare a variable with `$` and name `=` and then what you want that variable to define.  Since you want to COUNT the number of texts, and the above command pulls that information, we can use that information in a variable to COUNT.

```
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt"
```

Now we just need it to COUNT the results of the variable.  To do that we call the variable and tell it to count the results, like this:

```
$Stuff.count
```

Boom!  There's your number.  I think you understand IF statements, so let's just say IF that number is GREATER THAN 1, you want to open the directory.  Otherwise you want to move the item and start a program.

```
If($Stuff.count -gt "1"){
   Invoke-Item "C:\MyDirectory"
}
Else{
   Move-Item "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt" "C:\MyOtherDirectory\" -Force
   Invoke-Item "C:\ProgramDirectory\program.exe"
}
```

`If` statements are followed by their condition in parenthesis `()`, followed by the action in curly braces `{}`.  The flag (or operator) `-gt` means "greater than".  `Invoke-Item` is pretty obvious:  it invokes whatever item follows it with whatever your computer would do if you tried to open that item by invoking it with your mouse/keyboard.  I think you can figure out what the `-Force` flag does.

All together now, here's your script.  Change it how you see fit.

```
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt"

If($Stuff.count -gt "1"){
   Invoke-Item "C:\MyDirectory"
}
Else{
   Move-Item "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt" "C:\MyOtherDirectory\" -Force
   Invoke-Item "C:\ProgramDirectory\program.exe"
}
```

Welcome to PowerShell!  There's your freebie.  Please learn!  Look at the "Hey!  Scripting Guy!" blogs and use the CRAP out of TechNet for help!

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the downvote!  The kid needs help.  It's his first day!  Maybe try to make him a resource as opposed to being ticked that he didn't read the ToS.  Capital job.

Comment: Thanks very much!
This worked great.
I also wanted to make sure the program doesn't run (or else it will run if said file isn't there and stay open)
So I modified it a bit and simply added, within the Else{
If($Stuff.count -eq "1"){
And then the rest of the code that was there.
Now it doesn't run if no file got moved, working beautifully!
Thanks for explaining each of the parts of it too, this has helped greatly.
I hope to go on to expand this now with some more studying to trigger an email based on what it finds!
Pretty impressed by Powershell so far.

Comment: So, actually yours does work, which is what I ran, but my addition doesn't work, I edited the code so the program wouldn't run if there was nothing in the older, only if it moves 1 file. <br/>
`$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt"`<br/>
    
    If($Stuff.count -gt "1"){
       Invoke-Item "C:\MyDirectory"
    }
    Else{

       Move-Item "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt" "C:\MyOtherDirectory\" -Force
       Invoke-Item "C:\ProgramDirectory\program.exe"`
    }

Comment: Failed to add markup to the above and then wouldn't let me re-edit, here is my code that doesn't work;
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyDirectory\*.txt"
If($Stuff.count -gt "1"){ Invoke-Item "C:\MyDirectory" } 
Else{ 
If($Stuff.count -eq "1"){
Move-Item "C:\MyDirectory*.txt" "C:\MyOtherDirectory\" -Force Invoke-Item "C:\ProgramDirectory\program.exe"
}
}

Comment: Think I may have sorted it but changing the Else to an ElseIf, can confirm tomorrow morning when I need to run this script again, but I'm not sure fi then not having just an Else at the end will cause a problem.

Comment: So the ElseIf doesn't stop the program from running if it doesn't pickup a file.

Is there a way to force it to end if it doesn't move a file?
I would expect the following to only run if the $stuff.count is equal to 1
ElseIf 
 ($Stuff.count -eq "1")
 {
  Move-Item "mydirectory*.csv" "mynewdirectory" -Force
  Invoke-Item "myprogram"
 }

Comment: The proposed approach with `Get-ChildItems` and then checking for the child item count sounds unnecessary convoluted to me. I just started using PowerShell and I assumed there must be a better way. Indeed - `Test-Path` is a more suitable function to check for the presence of file(s) incl. those matching a file pattern. 
Therefore the entire `((Get-ChildItem "MyDirectory\*.txt").count -gt "1")` condition could be replaced with a shorter and more intuitive `(Test-Path "MyDirectory\*.txt")` that returns `True` if there's at least one file matching this file pattern and `False` if there are none.